# npx create-react-app SOLO me descarga el package.json

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, npm

Al crear la app desde la consola, se me descarga el `package.json` y queda ahí.
no continúa descargando el resto de las carpetas y archivos.

Comment: tal vez algo aqui pueda servirte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135589/create-react-app-only-creates-package-json-file

Comment: podrías agregar el comando con el que estas intentando crear el proyecto react?

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez puedas probar con esto:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app
```

para rehacer la instalación de manera global

Comment: Hola, agrega una explicación, Leer [answer], saludos.

Comment: La explicación, es probar esos comandos para rehacer la instalación de manera global. No tiene mucha pérdida

Comment: @PabloBravoLópez he agregado esa explicacion a la respuesta ya que los comentarios generalmente son menos visibles